# How to enable background notification in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-notifications

I'm using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin to handle notifications in my project.

I'm trying to turn on **background notifications**, I followed those steps: [Optionally handle background messages](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#optionally-handle-background-messages) from plugin documentation.

But it didn't work.

I searched for a solution and found this:

**Adding the plugin dependencies in `app/build.gradle`**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```

But it didn't work, too.

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
```